Image chooser close on swipe down on Android
The image selection window closes when I swipe down, I'd like to turn this off but I can't find any documentation.
I have one function for selecting files and images. When I open the file selection, a window appears that does not close with a swipe, and when I select images, another window appears that can be minimized with a swipe down. This irritates users of the application. Tell me, is it possible to disable this?
screenshot
My code
 webAppView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
            }
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType){
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                String[] types = {acceptType};
                openImageChooser(types);
            }

            // For Lollipop 5.0+ Devices

            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                mUploadMessages = filePathCallback;
                //Log.d("file", Arrays.toString(fileChooserParams.getAcceptTypes()));
                openImageChooser(fileChooserParams.getAcceptTypes());
                return true;
            }


            //openFileChooser for other Android versions

            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
            }

            private void openImageChooser(String[] types_array) {
                try {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

                    i.setType("*/*");
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, types_array);

                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Files Chooser");

                    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                if (progress == 100) {
                    preload_img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }

        });

and
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Uri[] results = null;
        try {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                results = null;
            } else {
                if (data != null) {
                    String dataString = data.getDataString();
                    ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
                    if (clipData != null) {
                        results = new Uri[clipData.getItemCount()];
                        for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                            ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                            results[i] = item.getUri();
                        }
                    }
                    if (dataString != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }
                } else {
                    results = new Uri[]{mCapturedImageURI};
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mUploadMessages.onReceiveValue(results);
        mUploadMessages = null;
    }

manifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyDudes"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name="ru.my_dudes.mydudesapp.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <tools:validation testUrl="https://myapp.app/" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="myapp.app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="ru.my_dudes.mydudesapp.ForegroundGpsService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:foregroundServiceType="location"
            android:stopWithTask="false"></service>
        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
</manifest>


upload full code where you have placed this function.

OK
I updated the text of the question


When I open the file selection, a window appears that does not close with a swipe

It does that on the particular device(s) that you are testing. The behavior of this Intent will vary by device model, and there are tens of thousands of device models.

Tell me, is it possible to disable this?

There are no documented Intent extras that control this behavior for ACTION_GET_CONTENT, sorry.
You might consider switching to a more modern approach and see if you like the results better.

Thank you. But it depends on the version of Android. This behavior starts with version 13 or 12. I tested on Xiaomi on Android 13, Samsung Galaxy S23 with Android 14 and Google Pixel 9Pro with Android 15. There is no such problem on the device with Android 10. That's why I'm interested in the possibility of changing the behavior of this window.

Looks like I found a solution that suits me. You need to replace ACTION_GET_CONTENT with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, then another window opens.
